# what does <=> mean in grails sort

Tags: sorting, grails

I know this seems to be a stupid question but I cannot figure out what

```
def Nodes = Node.findAllByParent(theNode).sort{ a, b -> a.label <=> b.label }
```

does? The Node class contains label and other attributes. I want to know what the sort thing in the above line does. theNode is like a parent node which has children. and how is it different from

```
def Nodes = Node.findAllByParent(theNode,sort['label'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a <=> b
```

is shorthand for

```
a.compareTo(b)
```

which itself is equivalent to:

```
if (a > b) {
  return 1

} else if (a < b) {
  return -1

} else {
  // a and b are equal
  return 0
}
```

The difference between

```
def Nodes = Node.findAllByParent(theNode).sort{ a, b -> a.label <=> b.label }
```

and

```
def Nodes = Node.findAllByParent(theNode,sort['label'])
```

is that the first one does the sorting in-memory, whereas in the second case the nodes are returned in sorted order by the query. In general you should let the database do the sorting where possible.

By the way, I think the second parameter above should be `[sort: "label"]` rather than `sort['label']`.

Answer (score 1):

The first `sort` is done as a Groovy sort on the collection where as the second is using the sorting capabilities of the data source (e.g. database ORDER BY).

The `<=>` is known as the spaceship operator. The operator is another way of referring to the compareTo method of the Comparable interface. This means we can implement the compareTo method in our own classes and this will allow us to use the <=> operator in our code. And of course all classes which already have implemented the compareTo method can be used with the spaceship operator. The operator makes for good readable sort methods.

For example:

```
class Person implements Comparable {
    String username
    String email

    int compareTo(other) {
        this.username <=> other.username
    }
}

assert -1 == ('a' <=> 'b')
assert 0 == (42 <=> 42)
assert -1 == (new Person([username:'foo', email: 'test@email.com']) <=> new Person([username:'zebra', email:'tester@email.com']))
assert [1, 2, 3, 4] == [4, 2, 1, 3].sort{ a, b -> a <=> b }
```

Comment: does the compateTo method differentiate between Uppercase and LowerCase alphabets ? what I mean is in the result I found that the lower case always came after the upper case i.e they were not sorted (upper case words were sorted among them as lower case were sorted among them but not together)

Comment: `String.compareTo` is case sensitive, but there's another method `compareToIgnoreCase` which is case insensitive